# Facebook Graph API pulling user likes

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to pull a user's facebook likes. If I make the call for each user individually then the call is successful, but if I loop through the users in my database then the call immediately fails. The script is as below. Any idea why this is happening. And what is the solution?

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('***', '***', '*****');
mysql_select_db('*****', $conn);

//Application Configurations
$site_url = $webPath . 'index.php';

try {
    require_once $behindPath . "src/facebook.php";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e);
}


// Create our application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
        ));

//$usertoken = $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
// Get User ID
try {
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    header("Location: error.php?err= Some Error has occured. Please try again Later.");
    die();
}


//if($user){
//$accessToken  = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

//the following is the query to get the facebook ids of users whose likes have not already been pulled

```
$query = "SELECT uid, facebook_access_token FROM fbusers WHERE facebook_id IN(SELECT facebook_id FROM user_self WHERE device = 'ios' AND facebook_id NOT IN(SELECT facebook_id FROM user_interest) ORDER BY id DESC)";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($res);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $access_token = $row['facebook_access_token'];
    $uid = $row['uid'];
    echo $uid . "<br />";

    try {

        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $usertoken = $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token); //echo $usertoken; exit;
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }


/////////////////////////
//  Insert Likes
/////////////////////////
// prepare array for insertion
    $I = $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    $me_v = $facebook->api('/me/movies');
    $me_t = $facebook->api('/me/television');
    $me_b = $facebook->api('/me/books');
    $me_m = $facebook->api('/me/music');

// For movies Likes
    foreach ($me_v['data'] as $key => $value) {
        //d($value); 
        $update[] = $I['id'];
        $update[] = $value['id'];
        $update[] = $value['name'];
        $update[] = 'movie';

        $insert_intrests->execute($update);
        $update = '';
    }
// For tv shows Likes
    foreach ($me_t['data'] as $key => $value) {
        //d($value); 
        $update[] = $I['id'];
        $update[] = $value['id'];
        $update[] = $value['name'];

        $tv_str = str_replace(" ", "_", 'Tv show');
        $update[] = $tv_str;

        $insert_intrests->execute($update);
        $update = '';
    }
// For Books Likes
    foreach ($me_b['data'] as $key => $value) {
        //d($value); 
        $update[] = $I['id'];
        $update[] = $value['id'];
        $update[] = $value['name'];
        $update[] = 'book';

        $insert_intrests->execute($update);
        $update = '';
    }

// For music Likes
    foreach ($me_m['data'] as $key => $value) {
        //d($value); 
        $update[] = $I['id'];
        $update[] = $value['id'];
        $update[] = $value['name'];
        $update[] = 'music';

        $insert_intrests->execute($update);
        $update = '';
    }

/////////////////////////
//  END Insert Likes 
/////////////////////////
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Catch the exceptions the API calls might throw.

Comment: What error message are you getting? Which line? Is the error being returned by Facebook or another aspect of your code?  Are they long lived access tokens or have they expired? Does your access token have the necessary permission to make the call?